# Does commenting before registering on forums have any draw backs?

Tags: forum

I'm redesigning a forum and one of the issues we earlier faced is the drop off rate during signing up. One of the reasons we did find was there being too many questions asked by an admin during this process and we're addressing that.

The current flow is such that if a user needs to comment on a topic:
 1. the user needs to register
 2. then validate email ID 
 3. come back to comment

We want to prevent the user from having to come back to the page to comment and were wondering if having them commenting before registering made sense? And should we even venture down that path?

Comment: I've often been in a situation where you could comment before entering any credentials. Then you click "Post" and here comes the registration. Personally I don't like it when they don't tell me ahead of time. There's also the chance of registration (or log in) failing, and then the user loses the content of their post (that has happened to me A LOT).

Answer (score 2):

Things to consider:

- spam: if you publish comments that anyone (any bot) can post, expect a lot of spam.
- illegal or abusive content: freedom of speech is great unless you can be held accountable for publishing someone else's opinions or intentionally controversial posts.
- legals: should you be associating a cookie and storing data associated to a person prior to the acceptance of privacy policy and terms/conditions?
- cost: for moderating, in legal fees, etc.

One approach that could work well is to:

1. accept unauthorised comments as long as the person accepts terms & privacy policy as part of that process or prior to.
2. moderate the first n unauthorised comments per unauthed user, if any problems with a particular unauthed user then flag them. If serious problems then reject them if/when they want to register and autoreject any more comments they may post.